# How to test React template block in a component

Tags: reactjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a little React component - Template block statement.
But do I can to do that? Because I can't even log that block statement from **renderResult()** method.

Is it possible? Only One way I see. It's just test the end result via Enzume Shallow. But I just wonder - is it possible?

Thanks for any info.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react";

export function zeta() {
    return "zeta";
}

export default class AppComponent extends React.Component {

    some() {
        return "some";
    }

    renderResult() {
        let res;

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            res =  ( <main><h1>App Component PROD</h1>{ this.props.children }</main> );
        } else {
            res = ( <main><h1>App Component DEV 11</h1>{ this.props.children }</main> );
        }

        return res;
    }

    render() {
        return this.renderResult();
    }

}

AppComponent.propTypes = {
    children : PropTypes.object
};
```

My test

```
import jasmineEnzyme from "jasmine-enzyme";

import React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";

import AppComponent, {zeta} from "../App.component";

describe("<AppComponent /> test", () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmineEnzyme();

        wrapper = mount(<AppComponent />);
    });

    it("App Component should contain h1", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find("h1")).toBePresent();
    });

    it("h1 Should contain a dev text in case of dev mode", () => {
        const compInst = wrapper.instance();
        const res = compInst.some();

        console.log(compInst.renderResult());

        console.log(res);
        expect(res).toMatch("some");
    });
});


});
```

Comment: So I resolved this just like I told before. I tested the html-result via Enzume. I didn't found answer to the question above, unfortunately.